# Make Async Rest Request

Tags: c#, .net, rest, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to make some Rest Requests on Windows Phone.

But I am struggling to use  "Aync/await" with the functions that I use :

For example with this function  :

```
   private  void Function() 
        {
            var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://exampleapi.com");
            client.Authenticator = [....]
            var request =  new RestSharp.RestRequest("/example.json", Method.GET);
            try
            {
                client.ExecuteAsync(request, reponse =>
                {
                    if (reponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {


              // Operations with the json...
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }
```

I tried to add the word `async` like this :

```
private async void restsharptest() 
            {
                var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://exampleapi.com");
                client.Authenticator = [....]
                var request =  new RestSharp.RestRequest("/example.json", Method.GET);
                try
                {
                    client.ExecuteAsync(request, reponse =>
                    {
                        if (reponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {


  var timeline =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(reponse.Content);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                }
            }
```

Buth then when I try  add await :

```
var timeline = await  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(reponse.Content);
```

I get the following errors :

> Impossible to reach 'System.Collections.Generic.List

and  :

> Operator 'await' can only be used in a lambda expression async. Mark
>   this with lambda expression modifier 'async'.

How can I use `async/await`  my  "Function1" ?

EDIT :

```
 client.ExecuteAsync(request, response  =>
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    List_ = new List<Myobject>();
                    List_ = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Myobject>>(response.Content));
                    tcs.SetResult(RefreshList_);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }
            });
```

I have this error again :

> Operator 'await' can only be used in a lambda expression async. Mark
>   this with lambda expression modifier 'async'.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to use async you should do the following:

```
private async void Function() 
{
     var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://exampleapi.com");
     client.Authenticator = [....]
     var request =  new RestSharp.RestRequest("/example.json", Method.GET);
     try
     {
         var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

         if (reponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
         {
             // Operations with the json...
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Error");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception error)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
     }
  }
```

Notice the difference between your `ExecuteAsync` and the `ExecuteTaskAsync` with the await before.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `await` (wait) completion of methods marked as `async` where return type is either `Task` or `Task<T>` (and in special cases `void`). `async` keyword allows the use of `await` keyword inside the method/lambda.

Marking lambda as async

```
class.Method(() => { /* Do something sync*/ };
class.Method(async () => { /* Do something async */ };
```

In your case you could do something like

```
{
    ...
    var client = new RestClient(serviceBaseUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest(serviceUrl, Method.GET);
    var content = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
    var somethingToReturn = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(content));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I added an edit in my post!

Comment: Making IO-bound parts asynchronous (using `client.ExecuteTaskAsync()`) is a good idea, but using `async` for the the CPU-bound deserialization isn't really going to yield any better performance--unless the document be deserialized is truly huge, and you really need to offload to another thread.